sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked, when updating and deleting a record
I am trying to update and delete records in a database using sqlite3
and I am getting this error message. When I run the program again the instruction is completed.
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\VolleyballApp\Venv\Frames.py", line 336, in <lambda>
    remove_button = Button(button_frame, text="Remove", command=lambda: remove_record(id_entry))
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\VolleyballApp\Venv\Frames.py", line 460, in remove_record
    conn.commit()
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

        def remove_record(x):
            print("Removed")
            conn = sqlite3.connect("player_record.db")
            c = conn.cursor()
            id = x.get()
            print(id)
            c.execute("DELETE FROM MyPlayers WHERE playerID = ?", (id, ))
            conn.commit()
            delete_entries()
            display()

conn = sqlite3.connect("player_record.db")
            c = conn.cursor()
            id = x.get()
            name = fn_entry.get()
            surname = ln_entry.get()
            bd = bd_entry.get()
            position = pos_entry.get()
            height = height_entry.get()
            weight = weight_entry.get()
            sql = (
                "UPDATE MyPlayers SET player_name=?, last_name = ?, birthDate = ?, position = ?, height = ?, weight = ? WHERE playerID = ?"
            )
            args = (name, surname, bd, position, height, weight, id)
            c.execute(sql, args)
            print("Updated")


it is quite unclear when you call your remove_record, but in short after deleting all recods of player say 1 you can not uodate any rows

I don't see a commit in your second code block.
